# Angular downgrade from version 5 to 4

Tags: angular, angular-cli

i want to create angular 4 project instead of 5.
my angular cli version 1.5.0
when i run this command to downgrade the version to angular cli 4

```
npm install -g angular-cli@1.4.9
```

I get the error

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for angular-cli@1.4.9
```

Comment: I imagine that'd be in the angular docs to remove and install to different version.

Comment: I just find the command I wrote but maybe the version I set it's not correct

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to install this specific version of the angular cli you have to use this command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.9
```

Perhaps you have another version currently installed on your system you should read [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli) also.

Comment: To check available versions: npm view @angular/cli versions - looks like 1.6.8 is Angular 4

Comment: "ng -v" yields: Angular CLI: 1.6.8 / Angular: 5.2.10 ?? What is wrong with the world?

Answer (score 0):

The version of angular used in a project is determined by the version of angular cli installed.
any specific version of angular cli can be installed with the following command:

`npm install --global @angular/cli@x.x.x`.

example:

`npm install --global @angular/cli@1.6.6`

even if you have another version of angular cli (either newer or older) installed. That won't cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

To install Angular 4:

1. Open CMD
2. `npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.9`

Check all the versions in below link:

[npm angular cli versions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli?activeTab=versions)