# How to migrate from angular 5 to 4

Tags: angular

I've just started learning Angular, I downloaded the latest version of node js and installed angular cli. I've then started working on a project just to find out that I need Angular 4 while I had it started with Angular 5

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "^5.5.2",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"
},
```

Is there a way to migrate back without having to restart the project ? Is there a way to specify which version of Angular to use when creating a project with `ng new` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular downgrade from version 5 to 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47186038/angular-downgrade-from-version-5-to-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code for package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.6",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.6",
  }
```

Run npm install on terminal/command-prompt and run your project. Now your are running angular 4 project.
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you downgrade ? Your project is brand new, why would you not use the latest version ?

And if you want to downgrade, simply replace the version in your `package.json` with the version you want.

This would look like

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^4.3.1",
  "@angular/common": "^4.3.1",
  "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.1",
  "@angular/core": "^4.3.1",
  "@angular/forms": "^4.3.1",
  "@angular/http": "^4.3.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.1",
  "@angular/router": "^4.3.1",
  "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
},
```

Just keep in miind that you need to also set the version of all dependencies, but your console will tell you, don't worry.

Comment: Excellent point IMHO. The difference between NG4 and NG5 seems to be mostly greatly appreciated bug fixes.