# Install alpha and beta version of angular using CLI

Tags: angular

I want to install a version of angular that is under active development and testing such as 8.0.0-beta, but I have installed version 8.1.0. How can go from version 8.1.0 to 8.0.0-beta?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of other related questions, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415235/how-to-change-upgrade-or-downgrade-angular-version

Answer (score 0):

Update the package.json with required versions for the dependencies and run "npm install". Fix any compiler issues that may arise. For further assistance if any, please follow the inverse steps of upgrading from 8.0.0 beta update to 8.1.0 from the guide https://update.angular.io/#8.0:8.1. But since its a minor version change, there shouldn't much of the issues when downgrading.